# PHP 7.3 and 7.4 fail to compile on Debian 9.13 with error checking SSSE3 CPU feature

Tags: php, debian

I'm working on updating a system from using PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.4, but I ran into a compiling error that I haven't seen before and I'm not entirely understanding why it isn't working.

```
In file included from /home/derek/php-7.4.11/ext/standard/base64.c:369:
/home/derek/php-7.4.11/Zend/zend_cpuinfo.h:143:9: error: invalid cpu feature string for builtin
        return __builtin_cpu_supports("ssse3");
               ^                      ~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Makefile:1286: recipe for target 'ext/standard/base64.lo' failed
make: *** [ext/standard/base64.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

And this is the configure command I used:

> ./configure  --with-openssl  --with-system-ciphers  --without-sqlite3
> --enable-exif  --enable-fpm  --with-fpm-systemd  --with-mysqli  --with-sodium  --enable-mbstring  --with-pdo-mysql  --without-pdo-sqlite  --with-config-file-path=/etc/php  --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

It doesn't report any issues with configure, only when it comes to compile. `configure` does state ssse3 is not supported on the system despite the fact it is listed when I look at `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should report it as such. But keep in mind that modern software may not be able to support antique computers such as the one you are trying to use.

Comment: Antique computer? It's a Debian 9.13 VM running in Digital Ocean...

Comment: Does `cpuid` also show SSSE3 is supported on your computer? Here (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) it's stated that "Support for SSSE3 built-in functions and code generation are available via -mssse3". Maybe something like this could work for you: `./configure CFLAGS='-mssse3" `

Comment: Passing that compiler flag didn't change the error. `configure` still stated ssse3 was missing and I got the same error in the post.

Comment: OK, then the antique computer that Digital Ocean is for some reason emulating.